# Use CASE to build SQL WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, case, where-clause

note: Updated, as I think I need to use something similar to CASE

I have a form which has 3 address inputs:

1. Suburb
2. Postcode
3. State

I want to use these 3 form fields to populate the where clause of an sql query (see below).

1. So if no input fields are entered, there is no where clause (and all rows are fetched)
2. If one or more input fields are entered the where clause is built using the PHP variables entered.

   ```
   $sql = <<<SQL
   SELECT 
   cs.customerRefId,
   cc.firstName,
   cc.lastName,
   cc.email,
   cc.phone,
   cc.mobile,
   cs.seekingAddressSuburb, 
   cs.seekingAddressPostcode, 
   cs.seekingAddressState
   FROM 
   customer_seeking cs
   LEFT JOIN
   customer_contact cc ON cc.customerRefId = cs.customerRefId
   WHERE
   cs.seekingAddressSuburb = $suburb
   cs.seekingAddressPostcode = $postcode
   cs.seekingAddressState = $state
   SQL;
   ```

Comment: I have got it working with:
WHERE
cs.seekingAddressPostcode = $postcode

but if the variable is blank I get an error

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is written in the php script, if it is this should work for you:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
cs.customerRefId,
cc.firstName,
cc.lastName,
cc.email,
cc.phone,
cc.mobile,
cs.seekingAddressSuburb, 
cs.seekingAddressPostcode, 
cs.seekingAddressState
FROM 
customer_seeking cs
LEFT JOIN
customer_contact cc ON cc.customerRefId = cs.customerRefId";
//isset checks to see if the variable has a value set at all
if(isset($suburb) or isset($postcode) or isset($state)){
    $sql .= " WHERE ";
    if(isset($suburb)){ $sql .= " cs.seekingAddressSuburb = $suburb ";}
    if(isset($postcode)){ $sql .= " cs.seekingAddressPostcode = $postcode ";}
    if(isset($state)){ $sql .= " cs.seekingAddressState = $state ";}
}
```

there are other ways if you have previously set values to those variables though.
Either reset them `unset($suburb)` or if they were set to a default value check to see if they no longer equal that default value `$suburb = ''` ... `if($suburb != '' or ...`. Let me know if you want me to explain these last two further.

reference:

-[PHP isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

-[PHP unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)